# Sync File from Website to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios5

I want to know Is it possible to Sync(transfer) File from Website to iPhone.. Example user selected book from website after click confirm on website it will automatically been transfer or store on iphone and can be open via custom app that I made....Now app still require to sync file via iTunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

One possibility is using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to do the downloading of the files. You can then store it in the Document directory for the App, which will allow the file to be backed up to iTunes.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206952/200567

There are other ways to download files though, such as NSURLConnection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806633/200567

Comment: Thank You...I am newbie so how can we link to website code example when user click download on website how can iphone app respond.. Because user will be Click download book "via" website and it should automatically starting download on app how do we implement